# Cron does not store logs into specified file, does not execute either

Tags: linux, cron

I have the following cron job which fails to execute. No logs are being stored, neither printed in the shell. What can be the issue?

```
(ubuntu) CMD (cd path\to\script && /usr/bin/python3.8 script.py >> /home/ubuntu/logs/script.log 2>>&1)
(CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

Comment: Why do you have backslashes in your `cd` command?

Comment: Is the `path\to\script` actually in your cron job or is it a placeholder for a real path that you don’t want to show?

Comment: Sorry for that, it's actually a placeholder - didn't meant to use backslash

Comment: Have you verified that the commands run outside of the cron job (i.e. from the command line)? Is `script.py` actually where the `cd /path/to/script` commands points to? You did include an absolute path (starting with `/`), instead of the relative path that's in your placeholder, did you?